# Sending json object to server in android

Tags: android, json, server

I am trying to send json to HTTP server with this JSON format:

{"deviceID":3852883413434, "depth":2,"location":{"xCord":46.232, "yCord":42.4421},"size":3}

and here is my code in android, but seems not working well.Maybe i need array for location or format my code.Any adivce could help thanks.

```
  JSONObject postData = new JSONObject();
    try {
        postData.put("deviceID", unique_id);
        postData.put("depth",((HoleSize)this.getApplication()).getDepth());
        postData.put("xCord",((HoleSize)this.getApplication()).getLattitude());
        postData.put("yCord",((HoleSize)this.getApplication()).getLongitude());
        postData.put("size", ((HoleSize) this.getApplication()).getSize());

        new SendData().execute("servername",postData.toString());
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: What is the variable that store the json response? @IvanHristov

Comment: location "has no value" is a json object "location":{"xCord":46.232, "yCord":42.4421}

Comment: i have class that hold depth,size , xCord,Ycord  but dont have object location. I should make object in class that has these  two values and parse it to json?  @Jorgesys

Comment: ok if you realy wants the object location you can get it with postData.get("location").toString() check my answer!

Answer (score 1):

Using the json response,

> {"deviceID":3852883413434, "depth":2,"location":{"xCord":46.232,
>   "yCord":42.4421},"size":3}

you must get the JSON Object to get the value of `depth` and `size` (contained in the same object) and then get the JSON Object of `location` to get the values of `xCord`, `yCord`:

```
      try {

            JSONObject postData = new JSONObject(response);

            String depth = postData.get("depth").toString();
            String size = postData.getInt("size").toString();

            JSONObject locationObject = new JSONObject(postData.get("location").toString());
            String xCord = locationObject.get("xCord").toString();
            String yCord = locationObject.get("yCord").toString();


        } catch (JSONException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

applying this to your code:

```
 try {
        JSONObject postData = new JSONObject(response);

        postData.put("deviceID", unique_id);
        postData.put("depth",postData.get("depth").toString());
        //postData.put("xCord", locationObject.get("xCord").toString());
        postData.put("location", postData.get("location").toString());
        postData.put("yCord",locationObject.get("yCord").toString());
        postData.put("size", postData.getInt("size").toString());

        new SendData().execute("servername",postData.toString());

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```